# Google Cloud: Disk labels aren't inheriting from instance templates or images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have instance templates with labels attach and image related to the template has labels attach as well, once the instance group spin up instances my disk aren't inheriting the labels from template or images.

I would like to know is there way to label disk which created by instance templates.

Comment: Summarising my last answer:  is there a way to label a disk which is created by instance templates? Not yet, but  there is a [Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/163152709) for Google to implement this functionality. Additionally, if you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way to inherit the Label of a Disk.
I tried to reproduce the behavior you mentioned but it is not possible at this moment.

1. I created an image (gave it a label) using a disk that already has labels.
2. Then created an instance template using the same image and gave it a different label this time.
3. I then created instance group using the instance template and a VM instance was created with label inherited from the *template*, but the disk created for this VM Instance didn’t have any label.

The inheritance only works at instance level.

I have found that there is already a ticket created for this [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/163152709), where you can track the updates for this request and you can ask for more information about it if you need it.